# Graph with $n >= 5$ having a u-v Hamiltonian path has κ(G)≥3

Tags: graph-theory

My understanding : 
Here, G is obviously hamiltonian- connected , and a Hamoltonian-connected graph with $n >= 3 $  is a  Hamiltonian graph. 
To show : $κ(G)≥3$ 
So to show it is atleast a 3-connected graph , we remove a pair of vertices say u and v . 
Now I don't have know to explain it formally , but since it is hamiltonian- connected , even if we remove these 2 vertices , the graph will still be connected right ? 
Which means that this graph is 3-connected and hence, $κ(G)≥3$.

Comment: Let me know if you need more detail in my answer.

Comment: @Joffan , Yes I do :)

Comment: @Joffan I agree with your answer , but I need a little more detail for this part: " If we then remove those two vertices, the remainder of the path still exists, connecting all remaining vertices" ,It's not that I don't understand this ,but a little more detail would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider any two vertices in a Hamiltonian-connected graph with $n$ vertices, there is a path of length $n{-}1$ that connects those vertices passing through every other vertex in the graph. We can identify the vertices along the path as $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_{n-1}, v_n\}$, with $v_1$ and $v_n$ being our arbitrarily chosen initial pair. If we then remove those two vertices, the remainder of the path still exists, connecting $\{v_2, \ldots, v_{n-1}\}$, the remaining $n{-}2$ vertices.

Since we have removed an arbitrary pair of vertices without disconnecting the remaining graph, we can be sure that it would take removing at least $3$ vertices to disconnect the original graph and it is thus (at least) 3-connected.

For example: a Hamilton-connected graph with six vertices, choose any two and there is a path between them covering every other vertex , remove those two and the rest of the path remains, keeping the reduced graph connected:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

[image] $\qquad$ [image]

[image] $\qquad$ [image]